# SSL certificate installation for a personal Portfolio using Flask | EC2 | AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, nginx, gunicorn

I have a flask app which is nothing but my personal portfolio website. I have hosted it on a ec2 machine on port 80. The flask apps configuration looks like this - 0.0.0.0 port: 80. I got a domain registered on Route53 and got it linked through Hosted Zones. Below is my website/domain.

[www.prabhusubramanian.com](http://www.prabhusubramanian.com)

When I access it, and it shows that it is "Not secure". As I did a research I understood that I need a SSL/TLS certificate to be installed. I have many questions now:

1. Do I need to host my website under port 443(HTTPS) rather bein 80?
   FYI - The ec2 instance has port 80 and well as 443 open to be accessed from anywhere.
2. Any specific method to install it? - can AWS Certificate Manager handle it automatically?
   OR should I install a certificate on the EC2 to be able to make the domain secured?

A bit confused the path/method to follow. And if there is any resource that someone can share, that would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

I have tried to look into multiple resources, and saw method on gunicorn or nginx and also AWS Load Balancer. And all of them are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal these multiple ways.

1. Setup flask to host the certificate from Lets Encrypt [Flask SSL](https://pythonprogramming.net/ssl-https-letsencrypt-flask-tutorial/) . Since you are familiar with Python already, this might be more suitable for you.
2. Using NGINX Proxy Manager. I personally using this to host my Home Assistant setup at home. I am using docker of this to port-forward 443 to the host behind it. This does support integration with Lets Encrypt to provide free certificate [NGINX Proxy Manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/guide/#quick-setup)
3. If you want a bit more hands on, using NGINX acting as Reverse Proxy on the same instance with a free certificate from Let’s Encrypt will be the cheapest I can think of. However, this does need configuration to run Nginx and use an automatic certificate issue/renewal.[NGINX RP with SSL](https://sheraziqbal.medium.com/adding-free-ssl-from-lets-encrypt-to-your-domain-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-ec2-509d9dc7b193)
4. If you are having scalability and security in mind, it is better with an Application Load Balancer however additional costs are involved here.[Link](https://devopslearning.medium.com/how-to-create-aws-application-load-balancer-5b83b84f46a0)

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. I kind of went a different route after a night of research, where I did not have to use the nginx. I used Route53 and ACM. That did the magic to provide SSL/TLS certificate for my website that runs as a flask app on ec2.
Happy to share if someone needs the knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: @PrabhuSubramanian, could you share the steps on how you associated ACM cert to your flask app?

Comment: Sure. I followed the video in this link. Please refer to the same. Also, if any of those steps is unclear, please let me know, and I shall list the steps that I followed in the following comments.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQP96EjRM98&t=620s

Comment: So you went with an Application Load Balancer which was the option 4 in the list I shared. I just wanted to confirm that as ACM only allows certificate association with services that are AWS managed like Load Balancers, CloudFront, API GW etc. Hence asked you to confirm the path you picked :)

Comment: Thank you for the links above. Super informative.